# Is it thread dump at starting spring boot application 2+ ? how do i stop or disable it?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wICUu.png)

Please take a loook

Comment: Does the application start up without errors?

Comment: Yes application is starting